# Checking if a column value is or is not empty in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I am working on a code wherin every time the code loads up, a value from the third column in a DatagridView is checked; if it is empty, it shows "Empty", but when it has value inside, it shows "Not Empty"

Im working with this Code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        For each row as DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows
                If row.Cells(2).Value is Nothing Then
                   MsgBox("Empty")
                Else
                   MsgBox("Not Empty")
                EndIf
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

But i get incorrect data, i have the values from DataGridView

```
--------------------------
    |NAME | AGE | TIME IN |
--------------------------
     PAUL    18
```

But it shows

```
"Not Empty"
```

In the first message and

```
"Empty"
```

On the second message, but I only want is to display only one message saying "Empty" because the third column on the first row contains no value.

Comment: Then use `Exit For` after you prompt your message to stop looping!

Comment: Your example has one row in the datagrid so it should only display one message and quit the loop immeditalely. Or you didn´t show us the whole example data.

Comment: Well that fixes the problem :) Exiting For Loop :)

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem :) Thanks

```
Try
        For each row as DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows
                If row.Cells(2).Value is Nothing Then
                   MsgBox("Empty")
                    Exit For
                Else
                   MsgBox("Not Empty")
                   Exit For
                EndIf
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Just FYI, if you are only checking a single row, there's no need for a For loop. Just use If DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(2).Value Is Nothing...etc